# How to setup universal purchases?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have an app *MyApp* which is available on

- iOS (BundleId: *com.compmany.MyApp*) and on
- macOS (BundleId: *com.compmany.MyAppMac*).

Both are separate Xcode projects and have separate records on AppStoreConnect (ASC).

Now I want to enable universal purchase. According to Xcode 11.4b3 [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_beta_3_release_notes) I have to change the BundleId inside the macOS Xcode project to the bundleid of the iOS app. This does compile, but I can't upload.

Is the macOS version to be integrated into the iOS AppStoreConnect record or does it stay separate ?

In my AppStoreConnect record for macOS I can't select the iOS BundleID...

Can anybody explain the steps how to setup universal purchase for existing projects on the AppStoreConnect side (and maybe on the Xcode side as well) ?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: As far as App Store Connect, my understand is that it will work exactly like it does for tvOS apps right now. If you go to My Apps, then click an iOS app, there's a button to add a "version or platform" on the left side. When this rolls out I believe macOS will be an option there.

Comment: @Chris did you figure this out?

Comment: The way I did it was to setup a new macOS app for the iOS bundleID and then change the bundleID of the macOS project to that of the iOS bundleID. This might not be a solution for you, but it was for me since the macOS App was not "in the field" at this time and so I could change its bundeID w/O probs.